# Make a class using the VideoCapture class

Tags: c++, opencv

Pretty new to defining classes, I run into a problem defining a VideoCapture object in a self made class. See code below.
I try to make a class that contains all the info about a videofile. So I initialize the videoCapture object. Which works fine, but then after the 'constructor' (fName::setAviName) did its work and I call another function of the class (fAvi.GetNumFrames()) the VideoCapture object became a NULL pointer.
Apparently the VideoCapture object is destroyed when my 'constructor' is finished. Other Private variables of the class work fine.

Tried to solve the problem with a 'shared pointer' but no succes.

Is the question clear? Is this possible what I want to do? How? or should I not bother?

Thanks a lot,

DS

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class fName
{
    std::string d_AvifName;  // name of the Avi file
    std::shared_ptr<VideoCapture> d_capture;

public:
    int setAviName(string const &fName);  //sets name in class
    int const GetNumFrames() const;
};


// functions: --------------------------------------------------

int fName::setAviName(std::string const &fName)
{  //sets AVI name in class and opens video stream

    VideoCapture d_capture(fName);

    if(!d_capture.isOpened()){  // check if succeeded
        d_AvifName = "No AVI selected";
        return (-1);
    }
    else{
        d_AvifName = fName;
        return(1);
    }

}

int const fName::GetNumFrames() const
{
    cout << d_capture->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << endl;
    return d_capture->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    fName fAvi;

    int IsOK = fAvi.setAviName("/Users/jvandereb/Movies/DATA/Verspringen/test_acA1300-30gc-cam5_000035.avi");
    if (IsOK)
    cout << fAvi.GetNumFrames() << endl;

}
```

Comment: `d_capture` inside `setAviName` doesn't refer to the class member, it's an automatic variable that is destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `fName::setAviName` creates a new local variable with the same name `d_capture`, and therefor the global `d_capture` is not set.

Instead of using a [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) you could just create a non-pointer instance:

```
class fName
{
    std::string d_AvifName;  // name of the Avi file
    VideoCapture d_capture;

public:
    fName(std::string const &fName);
    int setAviName(std::string const &fName);  //sets name in class
    int const GetNumFrames() const;
};
```

I also suggest to create a real constructor:

```
fName::fName(std::string const &fName) 
{
    if (!setAviName(fName)) {
       //throw some exception for example
    }
}
```

Then you'd need to change `setAviName` where you can use [`open`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-open):

```
int fName::setAviName(std::string const &fName)
{  //sets AVI name in class and opens video stream
    if(!d_capture.open(fName)){  // open and check if succeeded
        d_AvifName = "No AVI selected";
        return (-1);
    }
    else{
        d_AvifName = fName;
        return(1);
    }
}
```

Also you need to change `GetNumFrames` since `d_capture` is not a pointer anymore:

```
int const fName::GetNumFrames() const
{
    cout << d_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << endl;
    return d_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
};
```

Comment: That Great. Thanks a lot!! and quick too:) It took me a while to find were I went wrong. I think it is this: once the class is constructed the (real:) constructor initializes the private members and then only the video stream has to be opened. (?) Is it normal way of coding to use one member function in an other (this case the constructor)?